# Uninstalling and Reinstalling Anaconda

Tags: installation, arcgis-pro, python-3, pandas, anaconda

I had 2 versions of `pandas` (22 and 23) in my Anaconda environment for Python 3.6. One of the `pandas` looks like it was installed through Python 2.7 `pip`. Basically, I am unable to `import pandas` at all into my code. It has been recommended that I completely uninstall and reinstall Anaconda. This seems like overkill, but I am going to try it. Nothing I attempted using `conda` or the Anaconda environment console seemed to work. My question is, how do I safely uninstall and reinstall Anaconda without messing up my ArcGIS Pro environment or my Python 3.6 (do I need to uninstall and reinstall that too?!) Help!

Comment: Why do not you use a virtualenv? Check if you have no pandas.py file, I already made that mistake.

Comment: definitely reinstall anaconda. been there multiple times. complete reinstall is needed including arcgis.

Comment: @hugonbg probably because they are trying to use pandas with arcgis

Comment: I am not sure how to use a virtual env. Pandas works in the root environment. What folder would my pandas.py file be in? I am looking under C:\anaconda3\envs but I don't see anything?

Comment: @atxgis - for clarification, you mean the a reinstall of the arcgis module, not arGIS Pro or Desktop, correct?

Comment: @gwydion93 double clarification, are you trying to use pandas with (same script) the arcpy library or the arcgis library?

Comment: Mainly the arcpy + pandas/geopandas is what I currently need. The library `arcgis` is essentially the ESRI API for Python, right? I guess I don't currently need that.

Answer (score 1):

From command prompt run `conda uninstall pandas`. Make sure you're in the correct version by navigating to Anaconda 3.6 or 2.7 folder and Shift + Right Click to open command prompt or powershell for whichever version of windows you have.

Comment: OK, I was going to do that, but I said it was also going to uninstall my arcgis module.`The following packages will be REMOVED:

    arcgis:    1.4.1-py36h52c3b5e_1  esri
    geopandas: 0.3.0-py36_0
    pandas:    0.23.4-py36h830ac7b_0`

Comment: For clarity, are you using ArcMap? Normally ArcGIS10x folder is in C:/Python27 but Anaconda installs differently.

Comment: I am using arcMap and ArcGIS Pro. I basically copied my ArcGIS Pro env into the Anaconda env so I would have arcpy functionality. Arcpy doesn't come with Anaconda right out of the box.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Pro but ArcMap usually just uses Python2.7 is there a reason to have 3.6?

Comment: We use both Desktop and Pro. Pro is strictly Python 3.6^, at least my version is, and we are trying to move more towards using Python 3.6 in general. Anaconda with Spyder on 3.6 is my primary development environment.

Comment: Best chance to quickly resolve is to probably uninstall Anaconda and reinstall. It'd fix importing issues. I used to rename my python 3.6 .exe file to python3 or pip3 so you know where your installing when using pip.( 'pip3 install pyperclip')